# no reader available for interface List and MIME media type application/json with UTF-8

Tags: java, jersey, jackson

I make a REST call and I want to get back json, that contains list of MyClass objects.
Actually I get this exception:

> {"error":"A message body reader for Java class java.util.List, and
>   Java type interface java.util.List, and MIME media type
>   application/json; charset=UTF-8 was not
>   found","type":"com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException","stackTrace":"com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException:
>   A message body reader for Java class java.util.List, and Java type
>   interface java.util.List, and MIME media type application/json;
>   charset=UTF-8 was not found\n\tat
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:550)\n\tat
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:506)\n\tat
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:684)\n\tat
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)\n\tat
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:507)\n\tat
>   ..[more stack trace]..}

the code is:

```
public List<'MyClass> getLIst()
{

ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
config.getClasses().add(MyObjectMapper.class);
Client client = Client.create(config);

WebResource resource = client.resource(HOST_PATH).path(PATH).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);

return resource.get(List.class);
}

@XmlRootElement
public class MyClass
{ ... }
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, due to type erasure in Java, Jersey can't see what type the list is. You should change the last line of your getList() method as follows:

```
return resource.get(new GenericType<List<MyClass>>() {});
```

Then it should work.

Comment: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 5; unexpected element (uri:"", local:"id"). Expected elements are <{}MyClass>]

Comment: This solution does work, sunny's second exception looks like a distinct bug.